# What is the right syntax to use near '() now in mysql 5.6?

Tags: mysql

Well, I have been at this for some time now and need some help. Thanks!

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() now,

  `Body` TEXT NULL,

  `Created` TIMESTAMP NULL COMMENT 'This descrbes th' at line 2



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Newsletters` (

  `Subject` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT () now,

  `Body` TEXT NULL,

  `Created` TIMESTAMP NULL COMMENT 'This descrbes the newsletter.',

  PRIMARY KEY (`Subject`))

ENGINE = InnoDB



SQL script execution finished: statements: 36 succeeded, 1 failed



Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Could not get definition for ABC_Blue.view1 from server

1 views were read back.
```

Answer (score 5):

Misplaced parantheses,try

```
 DEFAULT now(),
```

But you want default now for an INT column?Maybe for timestamp column,in that case you do:

```
Created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Take a look here even if the field was datetime,you still couldnt set its default to NOW.

[Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)

Comment: @OGHaza My mistake I think the bad now was referring to a previous column,the OP hasn't posted the whole deal.Not that the next now is any good.